# Error when trying to run exported standalone java application

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I did an export from an AnyLogic project from Anylogic 8.8.5 to a standalone Java application. When I try to run this experiment standalone with the provided batch file to start on Windows, I get the error

```
Main method not found in class wandering_elephants.Simulation, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

The batch file call is:

```
java -cp model.jar;(and lot of more classpathes, see details attached) wandering_elephants.Simulation %*
```

model.jar contains subdirectory wandering_elephants and in this subdirectory Simulation.class

I tried all different kinds of Java runtime versions and some different projects, but it is the same error.

What could be the problem?

Attachment:

Detailed call

```
===================================================
@echo off
rem 
rem Run AnyLogic Experiment
rem 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
chcp 1252 >nul 
set DIR_BACKUP_XJAL=%cd%
cd /D "%~dp0"

rem ----------------------------------

rem echo 1.Check JAVA_HOME

if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" (
    set PATH=!JAVA_HOME!\bin;!PATH!
    goto javafound
)

rem echo 2.Check PATH

for /f %%j in ("java.exe") do (
    set JAVA_EXE=%%~$PATH:j
)

if defined JAVA_EXE (
    goto javafound
)

rem echo 3.Check AnyLogic registry

set KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\AnyLogic North America

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "%KEY_NAME%" 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ANYLOGIC_KEY=%%A
)

if defined ANYLOGIC_KEY (
    FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "%ANYLOGIC_KEY%" 2^>nul`) DO (
        set ANYLOGIC_VERSION_KEY=%%A
    )   
)

if defined ANYLOGIC_VERSION_KEY (
    FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "%ANYLOGIC_VERSION_KEY%" /v Location 2^>nul`) DO (
        set ANYLOGIC_LOCATION=%%A %%B
    )   
)

if exist "%ANYLOGIC_LOCATION%\jre\bin\java.exe" (
    set PATH=!ANYLOGIC_LOCATION!\jre\bin;!PATH!
    goto javafound 
)

rem echo 4.Check java registry

set KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "%KEY_NAME%" /v CurrentVersion 2^>nul`) DO (
    set JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION=%%A
)

if defined JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION (
    FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "%KEY_NAME%\%JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION%" /v JavaHome 2^>nul`) DO (
        set JAVA_PATH=%%A %%B
    )
)

if exist "%JAVA_PATH%\bin\java.exe" (
    set PATH=!JAVA_PATH!\bin;!PATH!
    goto javafound
)

rem 32 bit
set KEY_NAME=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "%KEY_NAME%" /v CurrentVersion 2^>nul`) DO (
    set JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION=%%A
)

if defined JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION (
    FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "%KEY_NAME%\%JAVA_CURRENT_VERSION%" /v JavaHome 2^>nul`) DO (
        set JAVA_PATH=%%A %%B
    )
)

if exist "%JAVA_PATH%\bin\java.exe" (
    set PATH=!JAVA_PATH!\bin;!PATH!
    goto javafound
)

rem echo 5.Check Program Files
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%ProgramFiles%\Java\j*" /o-d /ad /b') do (
    set JAVA_PROGRAM_FILES="%ProgramFiles%\Java\%%a"
    if exist "%ProgramFiles%\Java\%%a\bin\java.exe" goto exitloop
)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\j*" /o-d /ad /b') do (
    set JAVA_PROGRAM_FILES="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\%%a"
    if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\%%a\bin\java.exe" goto exitloop
)

:exitloop

if defined JAVA_PROGRAM_FILES (
    set PATH=!JAVA_PROGRAM_FILES!\bin;!PATH!
    goto javafound
)

echo  Error: Java not found
pause 
goto end

:javafound

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=4" %%A IN (`java -fullversion 2^>^&1`) DO (
    set VERSION=%%~A
)

echo Java version: %VERSION%

set OPTIONS_XJAL=--illegal-access=deny
IF "%VERSION:~0,2%"=="1." set OPTIONS_XJAL=

rem ---------------------------

echo on

java %OPTIONS_XJAL% -cp model.jar;lib/MarkupDescriptors.jar;lib/com.anylogic.engine.jar;lib/com.anylogic.engine.datautil.jar;lib/com.anylogic.engine.editorapi.jar;lib/com.anylogic.engine.generalization.jar;lib/com.anylogic.engine.sa.jar;lib/sa/com.anylogic.engine.sa.web.jar;lib/sa/executor-basic-8.3.jar;lib/sa/ioutil-8.3.jar;lib/sa/jackson/jackson-annotations-2.14.3.jar;lib/sa/jackson/jackson-core-2.14.3.jar;lib/sa/jackson/jackson-databind-2.14.3.jar;lib/sa/spark/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-client-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-http-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-io-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-security-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-server-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-servlet-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-servlets-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-util-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-util-ajax-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-webapp-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/jetty-xml-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;lib/sa/spark/spark-core-2.9.4-AL.jar;lib/sa/spark/websocket-api-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/websocket-client-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/websocket-common-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/websocket-server-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/spark/websocket-servlet-9.4.51.v20230217.jar;lib/sa/util-8.3.jar;lib/database/querydsl/querydsl-core-5.0.0.jar;lib/database/querydsl/querydsl-sql-5.0.0.jar;lib/database/querydsl/querydsl-sql-codegen-5.0.0.jar;lib/commons-lang3-3.9.jar;lib/commons-io-2.11.0.jar;lib/poi/commons-collections4-4.4.jar;lib/poi/poi-3.17.jar;lib/poi/poi-examples-3.17.jar;lib/poi/poi-excelant-3.17.jar;lib/poi/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar;lib/poi/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar;lib/poi/poi-scratchpad-5.2.1.jar;lib/poi/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar -Xmx64m wandering_elephants.Simulation %*

@echo off
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 pause
:end
echo on
@cd /D "%DIR_BACKUP_XJAL%"
```

Atachment 2
decompile of Simulation.class

```
// 
// Decompiled by Procyon v0.6.0
// 

package wandering_elephants;

import com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ModelElementDescriptorUtils;
import com.anylogic.engine.gui.IExperimentHost;
import com.anylogic.engine.AgentList;
import com.anylogic.engine.Agent;
import java.util.Random;
import com.anylogic.engine.Engine;
import com.anylogic.engine.Presentable;
import java.awt.Paint;
import com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ColorConstants;
import com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeModelElementsGroup;
import com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeTopLevelPresentationGroup;
import com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeImage;
import com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeOval;
import com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapePolyLine;
import com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeText;
import com.anylogic.engine.presentation.ShapeRectangle;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import com.anylogic.engine.elements.IElementDescriptor;
import java.util.Map;
import com.anylogic.engine.AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI;
import com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation;

public class Simulation extends ExperimentSimulation<Main>
{
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    public static String[] COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS_xjal;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    private static Map<String, IElementDescriptor> elementDesciptors_xjal;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final Font _text_Font;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final Font _text1_Font;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final Font _text3_Font;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final Font _text4_Font;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final Color _text_Color;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final Color _text4_Color;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _rect = 1;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _text = 2;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _text1 = 3;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _text3 = 4;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _polyline = 5;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _oval = 6;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _polyline1 = 7;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _polyline2 = 8;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _text4 = 9;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _image1 = 10;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    protected static final int _SHAPE_NEXT_ID_xjal = 11;
    protected ShapeRectangle rect;
    protected ShapeText text;
    protected ShapeText text1;
    protected ShapeText text3;
    protected ShapePolyLine polyline;
    protected ShapeOval oval;
    protected ShapePolyLine polyline1;
    protected ShapePolyLine polyline2;
    protected ShapeText text4;
    protected ShapeImage image1;
    protected ShapeTopLevelPresentationGroup presentation;
    protected ShapeModelElementsGroup icon;
    @AnyLogicInternalCodegenAPI
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 38284644110508400L;
    
    static {
        Simulation.COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS_xjal = new String[0];
        Simulation.elementDesciptors_xjal = createElementDescriptors((Class)Simulation.class);
        _text_Font = new Font("SansSerif", 1, 48);
        _text1_Font = Simulation._text_Font;
        _text3_Font = new Font("SansSerif", 0, 11);
        _text4_Font = Simulation._text3_Font;
        _text_Color = new Color(-7765933, true);
        _text4_Color = new Color(-16751872, true);
    }
    
    public Simulation() {
        this.setCommandLineArguments_xjal(Simulation.COMMAND_LINE_ARGUMENTS_xjal);
    }
...
```

Comment: well, does it work before exporting from the AL IDE?

Comment: Yes, it works in the IDE, every experiments I tested.

Comment: I now decomplled the class Simulation.class to look into it, I posted the beginning of this class if this is allowed here.

Comment: this won't help, tbh. Try compiling from a different machine or try running the compiled model on a different machine